# using qsort on a nested struct array

Tags: c, struct

Below are my Structures and qsort declaration (to be arranged based on nID)

EDIT:

```
struct items{
    int nID;
    int nQuantity;
    int nItems;
    float fPrice;
    char cItemName[21];
    char cCategory[21];
    char cItemDesc[31];
};

struct Register{
    struct items List[20];
    char cID[11];
    char cPassword[11];
    char cAddress[31];
    char cContact[16];
    char cName[21];
}; 

int main ()
{
  /*These are the contents of List[]*/
  Users[nInd].List[1].nID = 1;
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[1].cItemName, "iPhoneMAXMAX");
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[1].cCategory, "Gadgettronss");
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[1].cItemDesc, "This is an iphone");
  Users[nInd].List[1].nQuantity = 1;
  Users[nInd].List[1].fPrice = 100;

  Users[nInd].List[0].nID = 50;
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[0].cItemName, "iPhone");
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[0].cCategory, "Gadgets");
  strcpy(Users[nInd].List[0].cItemDesc, "This is an iphone");
  Users[nInd].List[0].nQuantity = 20;
  Users[nInd].List[0].fPrice = 50;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    qsort (&Users[nInd].List[i], 2, sizeof (struct Register), sort);

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    printf ("%11d  %20s\t %15s  \t   % 10.2f  \t\t      %2d\n", 
        Users[nInd].List[i].nID, Users[nInd].List[i].cItemName,
        Users[nInd].List[i].cCategory, Users[nInd].List[i].fPrice, 
        Users[nInd].List[i].nQuantity);
/*rest of the code*/
}
```

Ideal Output:

Product ID     Item Name       Category       Price    Quantity

1               Iphone          Gadgets       50.00       20

50              IphoneMAXMAX    Gadgettronss  100.00      1

Actual Ouput:

50              IphoneMAXMAX    Gadgettronss  100.00      1

1               Iphone          Gadgets       50.00       20

However, my problem is that when I display the contents of List[] nothing changes.

This is my comparator function for qsort:

```
int sort (const void*p, const void*q)
{
  const struct Register *ip = (struct Register*)p;
  const struct Register *iq = (struct Register*)q;

  if (ip->List[0].nID > iq->List[1].nID)
    return 1;
  else if (ip->List[0].nID < iq->List[1].nID)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: You don't show the relevant code, but it looks as if you wanted to sort two items in `Users[nInd].List`. If so, you don't need a loop, just call `qsort` once. (Also, the two items may already be in order. But it's hard to tell with what little you've shown.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort the elements in the `List` array using `qsort`, then do e.g.

```
qsort(Users[nInd].List, NumberOfElementsInList, sizeof(struct items), CompareItems);
```

This will sort the `NumberOfElementsInList` first `struct items` elements in the array `Users[nInd].List`.

Your comparison function receives pointers to the `struct items` elements in the array:

```
int CompareItems(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct items *item_a = (const struct items *) a;
    const struct items *item_b = (const struct items *) b;

    if (item_a->nID > item_b->nID)
        return 1;
    else if (item_a->nID < item_b->nID)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to "sort" only the two first elements in the `Users[nInd].List` array then there's no need for the `qsort` function, just compare the two elements directly and swap if needed:

```
if (Users[nInd].List[0].nID > Users[nInd].List[1].nID)
{
    // Swap the items as index 0 and 1, thereby sorting them
    struct items temp_item = Users[nInd].List[0];
    Users[nInd].List[0] = Users[nInd].List[1];
    Users[nInd].List[1] = temp_item;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this! I had a hard time figuring out what went wrong with it